# Buzzing in headphones after installing mkchromecast

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, kde, audio-jack

I have a Dell XPS 9370 running KDE Neon 5.19 (i.e. basically Ubuntu 18.04)

After installing mkchromecast to cast audio to my living room speakers via Google Chromecast, I am getting a loud buzzing sound out of my laptop's headphone jack whenever it is not in use. My headphones work great when I'm playing something, but whenever the signal ends, the buzzing comes back.

I tried to fix this by uninstalling mkchromecast, but it didn't fix it (via apt, the way I installed it). I also deleted `~/.config/pulse`(after backing it up) but to no avail.

I am out of my depth here, when it comes to what might have messed up my headphone jack during the mkchromecast installation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use   pavucontrol (pulse audio volume control) to check audio device   :  normally set to  "internal audio", check  also profile tab

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. This problem went away yesterday when I did the latest round of updates to Neon. I have no idea why. Thanks laugeo for taking the time to respond.